# How to set the length of a tkinter Scale widget to an existing value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

tkinter seems to only want to accept an integer for the 'to=number' parameter.

I'm trying to set this parameter to be equal to an existing value, in this case it's the number of instances of an object in a list.

What I tried:

```
inventory=['coin','coin','coin','torch','coin']

scale=tkinter.Scale(self, orient='horizontal', from_=1, to=inventory.count('coin'))

scale.pack()
```

What I would want here is for the scale to give me a slider that lets the user choose between one and four, or one and however many coins are in the list. But it outputs a scale that has one on the left side and zero on the right.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted; the problem must be elsewhere.  Perhaps the actual items in your `inventory` list have trailing spaces or different capitalization?  Or perhaps the list was empty at the moment you created the Scale?

Comment: @jasonharper you're a lifesaver, thank you. I was looking at the wrong issue. I fixed it by configuring the 'from_' and 'to' parameters at a later stage in the process. Much appreciated.